# & was unexpected when unzipping bz2 file

Tags: python, powershell

Hello I am trying to write a script to unzip bz2 files with 7zip and python.

First when I write

```
PS> & 'C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe' e D:\path\example.bz2
```

with powershell it is working perfectly.

So I tried that with Python:

```
import glob
import subprocess

target = r"D:\path\*.bz2"
tab = glob.glob(target)

for i in range(len(tab)):
    subprocess.call("& 'C:\\Program Files\\7-zip\\7z.exe' e %s" %tab[i], shell=True)
```

And I've got that error message: & was unexpected.
Does someone has an idea why ?

I am using Python 3.9.2

Comment: `&` is the call operator for **PowerShell**

Comment: Yes but if I undertood correctly, the call function copies what it is in quotes in the powershell so I am obligated to put it right ?

Comment: & is specific to Powershell. Since you are running this in Python, you don't need the & command. You should be able to simply omit it. Sounds like you are expecting to have access to Powershell commands, but that is not the case from within Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**By using `shell=True`, you're opting to pass the command line to the platform-native shell, which on Windows is `cmd.exe`, not PowerShell**, so your *PowerShell* command line fundamentally cannot be expected to work as-is.

If we take a step back: **you don't need to involve the shell at all in your `7z.exe` call**, and not doing so also speeds up your operation.

By *omitting* `shell=True`, the target executable and its arguments must then be passed as the elements of an *array* rather than as a single command-line string.

```
for i in range(len(tab)):
  exitCode = subprocess.call([ 'C:\\Program Files\\7-zip\\7z.exe', 'e', tab[i] ])
```

Note the use of `exitCode =` , which captures `7z.exe`'s exit code and therefore allows you to check for failure.

Alternatively, you could let Python raise an exception on failure *automatically*, by using [`subprocess.check_call()`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call) rather than [`subprocess.call()`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call)